# What is the use of IL file generated from .NET (using MSIL assembler- ilasm.exe)?

Tags: .net, clr

What is the use of IL file generated from .NET (using MSIL assembler- ilasm.exe)?

I read it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx
but i am not sure about the use of IL file generated from .NET (using MSIL assembler- ilasm.exe).
Can any one explain me?

Comment: What is the use of C#? This question might be too metaphysical for me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to use IL directly in those (admittedly rare) situations when a higher level language like C# doesn't provide the precision or features you need.

For instance, there are some features in `System.Dynamic` that are used from the dynamic languages such as IronPython that can't easily be used in C#. Going straight to IL can help in those situations where you need to mix languages, perhaps for a third-party library.

On the other hand, *disassembling* to IL can be very useful as you can find exactly what the code is that the compiler generated for your C# program. This is invaluable for micro-optimising performance issues, for example.

Answer (score 5):

`ilasm.exe` — the MSIL Assembler — is a *[Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) compiler* for the .NET Framework's native assembly language (=CIL or IL or MSIL for short).

This tool produces executable files by compiling IL assembly source files. It doesn't generate any “IL files”. The opposite is the `ildasm.exe` — the MSIL Disassembler — which does the reverse: decompiles a .NET executable into its IL source.