# MSIL and Dissassembly for debugging

Tags: .net, vb.net, cil

I have plenty of experience debugging .NET applications using the Visual Studio debugger.  I also have experience using WinDBG to successfully identify and resolve memory leaks.

I don't have any experience using ILDAM or the .NET dissassembly (displays assembly code generated by the JIT) to investigate problems.   When is ILDASM/.NET Dissassebly used to investigate problems? Are they there simply for educational purposes for developers who want to invent their own language)? I suspect not.

I have investigated this online e.g. here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387%28v=vs.71%29.aspx, but I have not found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we want to see the disassembled code we will go for the ILDASM tool and give the mapped path of the dll and see the disassembled code in the tool

Check [this](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1158-disassemble-code-in-visual-studio-instead-of-ildasm-disassembler.aspx) out.

From the Microsoft site:-

> This tutorial offers an introduction to the MSIL Disassembler
>   (Ildasm.exe) that is included with the .NET Framework SDK. The
>   Ildasm.exe parses any .NET Framework .exe or .dll assembly, and shows
>   the information in human-readable format. Ildasm.exe shows more than
>   just the Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) code — it also
>   displays namespaces and types, including their interfaces. You can use
>   Ildasm.exe to examine native .NET Framework assemblies, such as
>   Mscorlib.dll, as well as .NET Framework assemblies provided by others
>   or created yourself. Most .NET Framework developers will find
>   Ildasm.exe indispensable.

Comment: Thanks.  What about IL.  Is it any use to a high level developer using VB.NET etc, except for educational purposes? +1.

Comment: You might want to use IL directly in those (although rare) situations when a higher level language like C# doesn't provide the precision or features you need.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: From the source Thread:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668207/what-is-the-use-of-il-file-generated-from-net-using-msil-assembler-ilasm-exe.....For instance, there are some features in System.Dynamic that are used from the dynamic languages such as IronPython that can't easily be used in C#. Going straight to IL can help in those situations where you need to mix languages, perhaps for a third-party library.